# Returning the response from fetch to the function which called it

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have a code something like this:

```
function getData(query){
    fetch('some-url').then((res)=>res.json())
    .then((res)=>{
      return 'string'+res.data
    })
```

The above function is

```
var data = getData('text');
```

I want the getData function to return modified string to store it in the variable data.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Not an export in promises, but what if you tried `return fetch('some-url').then((res)=>res.json())
    .then((res)=>{
      return 'string'+res.data
    })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Dmitry didn't understand that

Comment: @NickParsons Not working. Returns promise <pending>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getData(query){
    return  fetch('some-url').then((res)=>res.json())
    .then((res)=>{
      return 'string'+res.data
    })
```

and call it like

```
    getData('text').then(function(res){
       //your code should be here 
       var data=res;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` to achieve the desired result

```
function getData(query){
    return fetch('some-url').then((res)=>res.json())
    .then((res)=>{
      return 'string'+res.data
    })
```

Then:

```
var data = await getData('text'); //You will get your modified string in the data.
```

Comment: It says 'await is only valid in async function'

Comment: You have marked Ahmed's answer as answer, does it solved your poblem?

Comment: Yes Harish, it does

Answer (score 0):

fetch is a Promise, and you can change data only in `.then` method after fetch returned your data.

```
fetch('some-url')
    .then((res) => res.json()) 
    .then((res) => 'string'+res.data)
    .then((res) => /* some code */) // in this string you can achieve data.
```